# Длительность жизни переменной, заключённой в шаред-указатель, в лямбде

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++11

Имеется участок кода, который вызывает сомнение в полной зачистке данных после их создания и передачи в лямбду. Сами данные:

```
void MyClass::testMethod() {
    QSharedPointer<QVariantList> ptr(new QVariantList());
    ptr->append(1);
    ptr->append(2);
    ...
```

И тут же, в теле этого же метода вызов их обработчика:

```
    QFutureWatcher<bool> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<bool>(this);
    connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<bool>::finished
        , [this,watcher,ptr]() {

        if(watcher->result()) {
            QVariantList res(*ptr);
            ...

            emit succeed();

        } else {
            emit failed();
        }

        watcher->deleteLater();
    });

    QFuture<bool> future
        = QtConcurrent::run(this
            , &MyClass::doWork
            , ptr.data());

    watcher->setFuture(future);
}
```

Не получается разобраться в том, очистится ли список данных? Или он продолжит существование и затрётся новым лишь после повторного вызова `testMethod()`?

Comment: а что если создать некий пользовательский класс с деструктором и посмотреть, в какой момент будет вызван деструктор этого класса. То есть вместо `QVariantList` использовать какой-нибудь свой класс

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov , да, спасибо, вероятно придётся. Попробую соорудить проверку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr`, если на него больше нигде нет ссылок, будет удалён ровно тогда, когда `deleteLater` сигнал от `watcher` будет выполнен в event loop потока, который содержит его. Вызов метода `testMethod()` совершенно не влияет на время жизни `ptr`, т.к. `ptr` локален для него — много вызовов `testMethod` просто насоздают новых `ptr`, вот и всё.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. У меня просто странное поведение наблюдается в проекте. Выполняется некий "работник", забирает память и не освобождает её полностью при удалении. Он наследник `QObject`, по завершению работы удаляется. Вызывает он вот подобный метод, что указан в моём вопросе. Список данных в шаред-указателе разный, и расход памяти то увеличиается, то уменьшается в зависимости от размера списка. Шаред строго локальный, никто больше на него не ссылается. А больше, вроде, нет ничего, что могло бы съедать память. Вот и грешу, что, может, шаред не очищается.

Comment: @alexis031182, ну такие вещи нужно отладчиком искать и вспомогательные классы/методы писать. В коде, что Вы привели, `ptr` удалится как я написал, а что там у Вас в реальном коде, это уже может быть совершенно другая история. Очень часто бывает, что не замечаешь какой-то мелкой детали,— а она есть.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, как правило сам виноват оказываешься. Значит, что-то ещё упускаю из виду. Тем не менее всё равно спасибо, т.к. момент, обозначенный в вопросе, меня так или иначе беспокоил.